# Wrap multiple validations in a context

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-5

With [validation context](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations.html#method-i-valid-3F) we can do:

```
validates :title, presence: true, on: :published
validates :content, length: { maximum: 50 }, on: :published
```

Is it possible to wrap multiple validations that share a context something like the following?

```
on: :published do
    validates :title, presence: true
    validates :content, length: { maximum: 50 }
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can **group validations using the `with_options`** method:

```
with_options(on: :published) do |record|
  record.validates :title, presence: true
  record.validates :content, length: { maximum: 50 }
end
```

See the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#grouping-conditional-validations), [this article](http://blog.arkency.com/2014/04/mastering-rails-validations-contexts/#where_it__39_s_fun_again) and the [sources](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/with_options.rb) for more info.